# fill border rect with custom color

Tags: ios, objective-c

filling rect with built in colour is working fine, but when trying to customise the colour with RGB code it will not work.

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:80 green:80 blue:80 alpha:1];
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
CGColorSpaceRef cgRef = CGColorGetColorSpace([color CGColor]);
CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(ctx, cgRef);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [color CGColor]);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
```

but using `UIColor.grayColor` for colour, works fine.
i tried also without modifying colour space, nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments for custom RGB codes must be CGFloats.

```
UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:80.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:80.0/255.0 alpha:1];
```

would be the correct way to specify your custom RGB color